# How to make a binding Edit an item in ListView

Tags: c#, listview, mvvm, binding, maui

I have started learning .Net MAUI. I am making a Note App for windows. I am also using the MVVM pattern, and for the first time. The problem is that I don't know how to implement Edit Cell in ListView. I add an item to the ListView, I can click on it and get information, but I don't know how to edit cells.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Notes}" ItemTapped="ListView_ItemTapped">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="{x:Type model:Note}">
                        <TextCell Text="{Binding Title}" Detail="{Binding Detail}" TextColor="#9a26ff"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>.
            </ListView>.
```

Here is the binding to the ListView

```
internal partial class NotesViewModel : ObservableObject 
    {


        [ObservableProperty].
        private ObservableCollection<Note> notes = new()

        [ObservableProperty].
        private Note note notes = new();

        [RelayCommand].
        private void Save()
        {
            Notes.Add(Note);
            Note = new();

        }

    }
```

I have started learning .Net MAUI. I am making a Note App for windows. I am also using the MVVM pattern, and for the first time. The problem is that I don't know how to implement Edit Cell in ListView. I add an item to the ListView, I can click on it and get information, but I don't know how to edit cells.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Notes}" ItemTapped="ListView_ItemTapped">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="{x:Type model:Note}">
                        <TextCell Text="{Binding Title}" Detail="{Binding Detail}" TextColor="#9a26ff"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>.
            </ListView>.
```

Here is the binding to the ListView

```
internal partial class NotesViewModel : ObservableObject 
    {


        [ObservableProperty].
        private ObservableCollection<Note> notes = new()

        [ObservableProperty].
        private Note note notes = new();

        [RelayCommand].
        private void Save(Note? note)
        {
            if (note is null)
            {
                Notes.Add(Note);
                Note = new();

            }
            else
            {
                note = new Note();
            }

        }

    }
```

Tried a certain number of ways. I can't show you an example

Comment: use an `EntryCell`, not a `TextCell`

Answer (score 0):

As Jason said, you can use the EntryCell which displays a label and text data that's editable instead of the TextCell.

For more information, you can refer to the [official document about define cell appearance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/tableview#define-cell-appearance).

In addition, you can also try to use the label and entry to achieve it. Such as:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Notes}" ItemTapped="ListView_ItemTapped">
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate x:DataType="{x:Type model:Note}">
          <VerticalStackLayout>
              <Label Text="{Binding Title}"  TextColor="#9a26ff"/>
              <Entry Text="{Binding Detail}"  TextColor="#9a26ff"/>
          </VerticalStackLayout>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>.
</ListView>.
```